# How can I use manifest.mix.js to generate a service worker for offline?

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, vuejs2, service-worker

I'm using laravel-mix-workbox to bundle and create a service worker. The service worker is running as expected, but there is apparently no precache files because it doesn't work offline (no content when offline after a reload).

Stack: Laravel 8, Vue 2, Workbox 6, Laravel-mix 6

```
// webpack.mix.js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
require('laravel-mix-workbox');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .vue()
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sourceMaps(false)
    .generateSW()
```

here's what I tried:

```
// app.js
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    const wb = new Workbox('/service-worker.js')

    wb.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
        event.waitUntil(caches.open('v1').then(cache => {
            return cache.addAll([
                '/',
                '/index.html',
                '/favicon.ico',
                '/img/app_bar_text.jpg',
 //             (etc...)
            ])
        }))
    })

    wb.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
        event.respondWith(caches.match(event.request).then(response => {
            if (response)
                return response;
            return fetch(event.request)
        }))
    })

    window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
        await wb.register('service-worker.js')
    })
}
```

But, the generated service worker does not include any files I specify and no content when offline.

Do I have to explicitly list every offline file? Should this list of cached files (urls) go in app.js or webpack.mix.js? If webpack.mix.js, then how?